Is it ok to say ".... 32 sports" when referring to 32 various fields of sports?
The Paris 2024 Olympic Games will showcase 3,800 hours of live sport and award 329 gold medals in 32 sports over 18 days of competition across the capital and in other parts of France. BBC-Paris Games
Is it all right to say "...32 sports..."? Or should it be "....32 fields of sports..."?

Using field in the context of sport usually suggests an expanse of ground on which a sport is played.

The phrase 32 fields of sports can’ be found in Ngram.  The only determiners shown with an * search are the and all.
Using the unit types gives us some results, in  two types of sports.
Ngram
Hence I think fields doesn’t work well in such constructions, and in the case here we would just say 32 sports.
